# Creating a Proof of Concept Infrastructure in Azure

Tags: azure

I'm looking for some guidance and/or maybe some pre-existing examples of standing up an example infrastructure in Azure.

Specifically, I'm looking at setting up some sort of load balanced web front end that talks to a load balanced database backend.

The goal is to have a PoC/Demo infrastructure running to validate external connectivity as well as ensure load balancing is working on both the web and database side of things.

Before running in-house applications, it would be nice to be able to stand up an environment for testing purposes that is completely standalone and is very simple to setup with a basic web page and database connection.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated. It doesn't have to be Azure specific mind you, but the goal is to set it up or replicate it's functionality in Azure.

Thanks!

Comment: For PoC please call the specific vendor, MS can do it, but dont know for AWS

Answer (score 1):

just create 2 sets of vms with 1 lb for each set, you can easily find examples of this setup online (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules) and put databases\websites on the vms.